# How to interrupt my script?

Tags: script, shell-script, kill

I use the following script (which I start from `at` command) as an alarm:

```
#! /bin/sh

set -m

while true; do
  paplay /usr/share/sounds/phone.wav
done &
```

I want to bind a key to stop this alarm. Please help to write a script which could locate and kill this process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following to the end of your script:

```
PID=$!
echo $PID > /tmp/wakeupalarm.pid
```

Then your killing script will be

```
#!/bin/bash
PidFile=/tmp/wakeupalarm.pid

[ -f $PidFile ] && kill $(< $PidFile) && echo > $PidFile
```

You should also run the killing script at the start of the alarm script, to ensure a single instance of the process.

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
#!/bin/bash
pid=$(ps aux | grep scriptname.sh | awk -F ' ' ' { print $2 } '
kill $pid
```

I'm sure there are better ways though.